# Are there any GitHub complementary services?

Tags: web-services, github

I'm looking for web services which use GitHub's API to implement additional functionality missing the the GitHub.

Know only two of them:

- [CodeShelver](https://www.codeshelver.com/) — A service to bookmark repositories.
- [Calendar About Nothing](http://calendaraboutnothing.com/) — A motivating service which build a calendar of your commitment to opensource.

The question. Are there any other such services?

Answer (score 1):

- [DocumentUp](http://documentup.com/) is a tool to help you build automatic documentation for your GitHub projects
- [GitHub Markdown Preview](http://github-preview.herokuapp.com/) is a pretty useful little app to instantly preview what your GitHub flavored Markdown will look like.

Are those the type of things that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, DocumentUp is that kind of thing. Thank you!

Comment: Shame on you, guys, who closed this question as not constructive! :)